# Unexpected endptr with strtod()/strtold()

Tags: c, gcc, strtod

I'd expect the `endptr` to point to the same value with both `strtod()` and `strtold()`.  Yet they differ.  I suspect `strtold()` is incorrect. OTOH, this could be a case where the spec is not clear and either result is acceptable.

Is this a bug (and with which function) or undefined/unspecified behavior?

Using: gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\4.8.3

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Edit - This include is in my true code, but was missing in original post
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *s = "123ez";
    char *endptr;
    double d = strtod(s, &endptr);
    printf("     double %f '%s'\n", d, endptr);
    long double ld = strtold(s, &endptr);
    printf("long double %Lf '%s'\n", ld, endptr);
    return 0;
    }

Output:
     double 123.000000 'ez'
long double 123.000000 'z'
```

[Edit]

gcc comand `gcc -I"C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\4.8.3\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c99 -MMD -MP -MF"string_fp.d" -MT"string_fp.d" -o "string_fp.o" "../string_fp.c"`

GCC 4.9.2

Comment: http://ideone.com/sCh4tn why ideone couldn't give the correct number...

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: There's a missing header: http://ideone.com/IIBYu0 We're not able to pass `-Wall` to ideone, but if we did, we'd see two warnings for implicit declarations of functions.

Comment: @BillLynch i directly copied OP's code. would that be a reason for op doesn't have a proper output?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: chux missed a header. `strtod()` is defined in `stdlib.h`. What's likely occuring is that cygwin's C library includes `stdlib.h` implicitly from the headers in the code. But glibc (which ideone uses) doesn't. So to get the code to not be undefined behavior, we should include that header.

Comment: @BillLynch  Thanks for the idea.  My true code did include `#include <stdlib.h>`  and I do see I missed that in the cut/paste here.  Sorry for the false lead.  I will update my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither should consume the `e`. To be allowed to consume the `e`, there must be a non-empty sequence of digits after the `e`. And GCC 4.9.0 with Glibc 2.12 behaves correctly.

```
[2:29pm][wlynch@apple /tmp] ./a.out 
     double 123.000000 'ez'
long double 123.000000 'ez'
```

Citing things from draft N1570 of the C 2011 standard...

> #### Section 7.22.1.3 Paragraph 3: The strtod, strtof, and strtold functions
>
> The expected form of the subject sequence is an optional plus or minus sign, then one of the following:
>
> - a nonempty sequence of decimal digits optionally containing a decimal-point character, then an optional exponent part as defined in 6.4.4.2;
> - ...
>
> #### Section 6.4.4.2 Floating Constants
>
> ```
> exponent-part:
>     e signopt digit-sequence
>     E signopt digit-sequence
> digit-sequence:
>     digit
>     digit-sequence digit
> ```

I would consider this a bug in the C standard library that you are running against.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug with `strtold` - the standard defines the syntax of an exponent part of a constant as (6.4.4.2):

```
exponent-part:
    e sign(optional) digit-sequence
    E sign(optional) digit-sequence
```

Where:

```
digit-sequence:
    digit
    digit-sequence digit
```

And `digit` is defined so that it can't be zero-length. So the numeric part after the `e` can't be zero-length.

The behavior of `strtold` is defined (emphasis mine):

> The strtod, strtof, and strtold functions convert the initial portion
>   of the string pointed to by nptr to double, float, and long double
>   representation, respectively. First, they decompose the input string
>   into three parts: an initial, possibly empty, sequence of white-space
>   characters (as specified by the `isspace` function), **a subject sequence
>   resembling a floating-point constant or representing an infinity or
>   NaN**; and a final string of one or more unrecognized characters, including the terminating null
>   character of the input string. Then, they attempt to convert the subject sequence to a
>   floating-point number, and return the result.

And the subject sequence is defined:

> a nonempty sequence of decimal digits optionally containing a
>   decimal-point character, then an optional exponent part as defined in
>   6.4.4.2.

And since the numeric part after the `e` in your example is zero-length, it isn't a valid exponent part.